# Why am I getting this error- "exit status 1 expected ';' before '{' token "

Tags: arduino-uno

```
void setup()
{

  pinMode{13, OUTPUT};

}

void loop() {

  digitalWrite{13, HIGH};

}
```

Comment: Use `digitalWrite(13,HIGH);` rather than curly brackets, and do the same for `pinMode`

Comment: Why ard you using `{}` brackets after function name?

Answer (score 3):

Try parentheses instead of curly braces:

```
void setup() {

pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

}
```

Comment: It's funny and nonsense, but `pinMode;  {  ... ` is formally correct. That makes error messages hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already give, but here an explanation:

`{` and `}` are used to group multiple statements together, either for a function, if, while, for loop and so on.

E.g.

```
if (i == 1)
{
  // Statement 1
  // Statement 2
}
```

or a function

```
void f()
{
  // Statement 1
  // Statement 2
}
```

`(` and `)` are used to specify parameters:

```
void f(int a, int b) 
{
  ...
}
```

A function with two parameters.

When calling this function, the following is used:

```
f(1, 2);
```

Calls function `f` with `a = 1`, and `b = 2`.

So in general: `{` and `}` is for grouping statements, `(` and `)` for parameters.

Comment: `{}` is also used in initializer syntax, which might lead to other confusing error messages for incorrect code.

Comment: @AnT True, I didn't make a complete list to make my answer not overly difficult for beginners. {} is also used for begin/end of a class as other example.

Answer (score 0):

I made same mistake when I started working with C

you have

```
pinMode{13, OUTPUT};
```

which should be

```
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
```

the curly brackets are basically for Start and End of a function.

Bill